# listenTo not firing event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to execute my view's render method but for some reason it is telling me that `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'listenTo' of undefined`, not quite sure why.

```
var App = Backbone.View.extend({
    current_election_index: 0,
    el: 'body',
    initialize: function() {
        elections = new Elections();
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.listenTo(this, 'change', this.render);
        elections.fetch();
/*      elections.fetch({
            success: function(test) {
                console.warn(this.App.render());
                this.render();
            }*/

        // });
    },

    render: function () {
        console.log('this is the render method');
        var view = new ElectionView({model: elections.at(0)})
    }
})
```

Comment: Do you have the latest Backbone?  listenTo was a pretty recent addition.  Also, I think you want your statement to say this: this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);

Comment: I did have an older version of Backbone (good call) and I did change this to this.model but now it complains that `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_listenerId' of undefined` and if I leave it as it was before, the event still does not fire

Comment: Well, that's telling me your view doesn't have a model. Which event are you listening for? Elections? So maybe this.listenTo(elections, "reset", this.render) ?

Comment: Tried that, it gets rid of the error but it does not do anything

Comment: Are you sure the fetch is working then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is listen to `elections`. So rather than listening to `this.model` or `this`,

```
this.listenTo(elections, 'reset', this.render);
```

The `reset` is triggered on a collection "when the collection's entire contents have been replaced". The `change` event is triggered on a model "when a model's attributes have changed". See the Backbone [Catalogue of Events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog) for more information.

If you want to update the view when each model belonging to the `elections` collection changes, be sure to do that in each `ElectionView` subview, not the `App` view.